# Bash shell continue nested loop over fresh files

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, scripting

I have a bunch of video clips and I want to pick a set of music for each of them.
I wrote a script which iterates over each clip and randomly pick mp3 based on its length.
E.g. if a clip lasts 10:30, then it adds up several mp3 which length sum is equal to the clip length.

```
#!/bin/bash
for v in clips/*; do
videolength=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $v | awk '{print int($0)}');
mp3s=0
names=""
    for m in music/*; do
    audiolength=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $m | awk '{print int($0)}');
        while [[ $videolength -ge $mp3s ]]; do
            (( mp3s+=audiolength ))
            names+=$v" "
            mv "$m" "used/$m"
            break
        done
    continue
    done
echo "music for this clip: "${names[*]}
# ffmpeg things here
done
```

This script works fine, except it iterates over same first mp3 from my list of 100+ mp3.
How can I **mark as used and skip already used mp3** and for next clips pick only fresh mp3?

Currently the script moves mp3 to another folder but it doesn't seem very wise.
Is there any smart way to iterate only over new files inside a nested loop?

Comment: Yeah thanks! I read about loop control like `continue N`, maybe it could be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
used=""
for v in clips/*; do
    videolength=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$v" | awk '{print int($0)}');
    mp3s=0
    names=""
    for m in music/*; do

        # check if the file "$m" was already used
        # "$used" is a newline separated file with names in it
        # we filter out "$m" from it. If it exists, that means that it was used.
        if <<<"$used" grep -q -x "$m"; then
           echo "File $m was already used"
           continue;
        fi

        audiolength=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$m" | awk '{print int($0)}');
        if (( videolength >= mp3s )); then # I guess you meant if not while, cause it has break on the end, so it acts as if
            (( mp3s += audiolength ))
            names+=$v" " # didn't you mean "$m" here?

            # save "$m" to the list of used files.
            used+="$m"$'\n'

        fi
    done
    echo "music for this clip: "${names[*]}

     # ffmpeg things here

done
```

You can save the used names inside a variable separated by newlines. Then use grep on the list to check if the name was already used.

Comment: You were right `names+=$v" "` should be `$m`. But currently your script loops from the beginning for some reason.

Comment: Should be `used+="$m"$'\n'` not `used="$m"$'\n'`. Typo